# Resizing componenets on a c# form

Tags: c#, user-interface, resize

typically in java if you have a layout manager of somesort, when you resize the page then the components in that panel will resize accordingly. I think my app is missing some sort of layout manager to control resizing as at the moment everything is just static

Is there a way to make it resize on the changing of the form size? say the user makes the page bigger, then the componenets adjust and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET has layout managers as well.

Personally, I prefer the [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) for my WinForms apps.

Once you layout the Table (using a combination of static/dynamic sized rows/columns) you add your child controls to the table cells. Once you add your controls, you can dock or anchor the controls to the cell so that they are automatically adjusted when the window is re-sized.

Comment: I'd also vote for TableLayoutPanel.  It can be a little bit finicky (especially programmatically), but once you get over the small learning hump, it can do a pretty good job of layout.  And if you can handle GridBagLayout on Java, you can definitely handle TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: +1 For completeness, I'll add that the [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) is also available, though it frustrates those of us who are particularly finicky about the arrangement of our controls.

Answer (score 3):

Two main options:

1. [Anchoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx).  Set your control to "anchor" to the sides of your form.  This means that if the form resizes, the control will stay a constant distance from that side.  So, if you anchor Top, Left and Right, then your control will stay in the same position, but resize horizontally with the width of the form.  Play with it.  It'll be obvious.
2. [Docking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx).  Set your control to "dock" to a side of the form, or the center.  This is usually done with containers, and it will make the widget take up that entire portion of the form no matter how large it gets.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Forms you make use of the [Control.Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property, which will cause the control to adjust accordingly when the window resizes.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with windows forms you use the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) and [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) properties of the control

See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6165908.html?tag=tr-left) for a guide on how to use them